# How to check the last time code was resync'd using SVN?

Tags: svn, collabnet

I am using SVN / Collab net. I read thru their commands http://wiki.greenstone.org/wiki/index.php/Useful_SVN_Commands but can't find the one which will tell me the last time a project was resynced / updated.  It would be nice to open a command box and then enter this command and immediately know when the last resync happened?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can see based on the revision number your working copy has that it is older...but not the timepoint where it has been update last.

```
svnversion
```

or
    svn info

But what you can test use the svn info and check the "Last Changed Date" line...